# Manipulating operators inside a String

Tags: php

This question might sound very weird and ridiculing but I was wondering if its possible.

I want to manipulate the operators that are present in String in PHP.
Eg:

```
$a = "3 + 2";
```

Is it possible to get the result as 5? Similary $a can also have another values like

```
$a = "3 - 2 "; or $a = "3 * 2";
```

In every cases, I want the appropriate result. But one operator will always be there in the String at the center. The requirement is, I want to know if the operator present in the String can be manipulated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how that? do you want to calculate the result? or to change the operator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `eval`. This is a function built into php.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: You don't __need__ to use eval() and it's recommended that you don't, especially if the expression is user input

Comment: Yeah I do know the ways you could go wrong with `eval` but just started php and don't know any other way to do it. It is one way though.

Comment: Look at the link I posted for "How to make a calculator in PHP" to see a good safe alternative in ircmaxell's answer